# Mule:AMQPConnector dispatcherPoolFactory-ref

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is there any working example for dispatcherPoolFactory-ref attribute of AMQP connector available? Documentation provides only minimal info(pasted below)

Description:Allows Spring Beans to be defined as a dispatcher 
 pool factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DispatcherPoolFactory-ref is not unique to the AMQP connector but rather all transports. It allows you to override the default Dispatcher pool by referencing a Spring configured instance of https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/MessageDispatcherFactory.html.

Here is an XML snippet showing how to configure it for the TCP transport:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-tcp/3.1.2/tcp-dispatcher-pool-factory-config.xml